# ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android

Hi and thank you for reading my question. I am a new so bear with me.
I have am app that I have divided into two activities

1. Find the server/Login and
2. display a TabActivity with three web pages that are generated on the server.

I have an ImageView in both layouts that acts as a splash screen while the WebViews are loading. It is tagged "visible" while the WebView and TabViews are marked "gone".

The signIn WebView is the main entry point and loads in the background. If all is good a page with the word "symbol" is loaded. My WebViewClient is listening with the `onPageFinished(WV,Str)` method.

Problem:
I can not seem to successfully call the TabActivity from the signIn Activity `(ActivityNotFoundException)`.
I have both activities listed in the Manifest.
I have done this in two of my last apps so I'm going crazy here.
I'm at the point where I may have changed too much code and have a blatant mistake. Please forgive me.

I have tried to `startActivity(Intent)` directly from the WVC and by calling another method `startTabView()` so there is extra code that is confusing.

I have tried declaring the Intent first, adding the component and calling `startActivity(context, intent)`.

I have written the one line `startActivity(new Intent("string class name"))`.

I feel like my intent may be null.

have a look:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    phoneID = "" + tm.getDeviceId() ;

    onStart();

}   



public void setLoginVisible(){
    ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    signIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    signIn.requestFocus();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

}
public void startTabView(){

    try{

        startActivity( new Intent(this,WizForex.class));

    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException anf){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), anf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

        wvc= new WebViewClient() { 
            @Override 
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 

                    if (url.contains("NCdisclaimer")) setLoginVisible();
                    else if (url.contains("symbol")){

                        startTabView();                         
                    }                   
                }   

            };

        signIn = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.signIn);
        signIn.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        signIn.setWebViewClient(wvc);            
        signIn.loadUrl("http://www.thewizard........"+ phoneID);




    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
 <!-- Splash View -->   
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/splash"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:visibility="visible"/>


 <!-- signIn View -->   
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.Eric.Sheasby.wiz"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name="WizFinder"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


    <activity android:name=".WizForex"
               android:label="@string/app_name">  

     </activity> 

     <activity android:name=".Tester"
                android:label="@string/tester">


    `
```

Sorry this is so long. What have I done?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are calling `startTabView()` from within an action handler (an other thread, not the ui!).

You should give a try instantiating a Handler (mHandler):

```
private static final int LOAD_TABVIEW = 10; //or any other number
private final Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case LOAD_TABVIEW:
                startTabView();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

and in your `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` method you should change a line

```
startTabView();
```

to

```
//send message to the handler:
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(LOAD_TABVIEW);
```

This way your mHandler's `handleMessage` gets called, and it should start the TabView.

Comment: My professor would be very upset. I am supposed to know who's thread I'm running on!

Comment: OK, I spent considerable time on this looking for my mistake. Now I wonder if you can start a tab activity this way. I still get ActivityNotFoundException when the Handler tries to start it.

Comment: I need to get something working. I keep hitting enter or this would all be one post (sorry). I am thinking of running my login code then loading the Tabs and showing them all in one activity.
   This worked before but I felt it was to much junk in one Activity...Please advise StackOverflow Geniuses !

Comment: it would be great, if you'd updated your question with the rearranged code, and let's see what we can find out. Also, if you could post the stack trace, would be helpful.

Comment: I've just noticed, that you are calling `onStart()` from your `onCreate` method. What is the purpose? You should leave it to get called on its own time. Please post your layout xmls and the main entry point class too, because it's a bit hard to figure out what is your application's architecture :-s